# I can't install Android SDK Platform-tools (Unable to locate adb)

Tags: android, adb, illegalargumentexception

I can't run android studio because (IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb) and then can't install Android SDK Platform-tools. I can't find anything online matching the error.

```
10:48:33 AM IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7j9P.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1gJc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have proper permissions on your OS to write files in that Directory .

Comment: go to c:\Android\sdk

right click on folder platform-tools

properties -> security 

and make sure you have Checked Full Control

Comment: or you can put SDK in other than system drive this will help you if suddenly you required format then you don't need to worry about backup etc

Comment: I use avast, so I go for virus chest, find adb.exe,restore it by clicking right button.. perfectly works. :D

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio/Android then rerun it as administrator